# Can't see hidden folder in Finder, but "ls" and "cd" work

Tags: macos, finder

On my external hardisk there are two folders inside a folder called "Sys". When I try to navigate to "Sys" using Finder (using "go to folder" option), I only see one folder inside "Sys".

When I use terminal to navigate to "Sys" folder and execute the command `ls -ltr` I can see both the folders and can also `cd` into them.

I also did:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

But the second folder is still not visible in Finder, and I also cannot navigate to it using Finder.

EDIT:the output of `ls -ltr`

```
  drwxrwxrwx@  5 net4uonline  staff   170 Aug  3  2009 Installation
  drwxr-xr-x  32 net4uonline  staff  1088 Aug  3  2009 Library
```

and for `ls -l@`

```
 rwxrwxrwx@  5 net4uonline  staff   170 Aug  3  2009 Installation
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
 drwxr-xr-x  32 net4uonline  staff  1088 Aug  3  2009 Library
```

Installation is the invisible one.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the folder has the `hidden` flag set? It should be visible when you do a `ls -lO`. Try

```
chflags nohidden /Volumes/your-drive/Sys/Installation
```

and see if that resolves the problem. You should always be able to open the folder in Finder with `open Installation`.

Comment: Thaks a lot ! i still cant see the folder using "Go to Folder" for some reason but `open` command did the trick for me!

Comment: You can try to remove the attributes with `xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo Installation`, maybe that works?

Comment: U R a Mac guru! :)